# Setting up a ddns service on my dreamhost account

Tags: dns, dyndns

I deploy cellular modems that currently have sims with static ip addresses. For various reasons, we may move to providing sims without static ips.

The cellular modem supports DDNS (bluetree modem). Is there any DDNS software that I can use so that I may tie each deployed modem to a sub domain of a domain I own?

Or is it better to just stick with a service and pay the fee?

Comment: Would this be a server fault question?

Comment: Did you get your BlueTree modems registered on Dyn successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a look at some available open source to provide a dynamic DNS service some time ago, and in the end decided to go with a commercial service, because none of the available solutions really convinced us, and we decided that keeping such a service running is not our core business.  If you want to know, we went to [Dyn](http://dyn.com/).

Comment: hmmm, I think that is probably the way to go for us as well. I need to figure out if these services are geared for lower device count and higher hits per device (ours is high device count and much lower hit per device)

Comment: @fvu , How did you get the BlueTree devices to register with Dyn? My devices only allow me to enter an IP & Port, not a username/password or device identifier. The user manual says the packet sent oly has the ESN and current IP. Not sure how to make this work together.

Comment: @Brendan we don't use BlueTree devices, but in most cases the dynamic dns will run on some client computer, not on the modem itself.  Also, don't forget this question is 3 years old, things may have changed in the mean time.

Comment: @fvu Understood, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, our deployment does not have a general PC running behind the modem, only another industrial data logger device. I commented here only because there are so few instances of questions related to trying to deal with this problem.